# Benchmark application for Android?

Tags: applications, benchmarks

There is any application to measure and publish benchmark results from Android devices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Quadrant](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard) and [Linpack](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.greenecomputing.linpack) are the two I use.  Linpack is purely for measuring CPU performance, whereas Quadrant also takes into account I/O speeds, graphics performance, and the like.